# ROS TF claims tree disconnected, but clearly connected

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am playing back some rosbag file.
In RVIZ, I see the error message "No transform from [area_description] to frame [start_of_service]".
TF view_frames agrees and shows the following:
[image: ROS TF tree]

However, when I export the rosbag file, /tf topic only, to .csv format, I can clearly see that there are 3 kinds of transformations in the rosbag file:

1. map -> start_of_service
2. start_of_service -> device
3. area_description -> start_of_service
   Whereas the left side is the value in "field.transforms0.header.frame_id", and the right side is the value in "field.transforms0.child_frame_id" in the resulting .csv file.

Now, the resulting graph is acyclic. If we choose start_of_service as root, this is clearly a valid tree.
The question remains:
**Is ROS able to invert the transformations so to form a valid TF tree?**

Apologies if this has been asked before. I was unable to find an answer on google or here.

Cheers!

- ibd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261185/ros-tf-claims-tree-disconnected,-but-clearly-connected/) by [ibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29147/ibd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TF doesn't allow transforms with multiple parents, and will reject new transforms if the child frame already has a parent.

You should be able to use the rosbag API to rewrite the transforms in your bag file to fix them.

Maybe you should make the `area_description` frame a child of the map or `start_of_service` frame, or maybe make it the parent of the `map` frame?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29147/ibd/) on 2017-05-08**:
I see, thank you for suggestions on how to solve it. Is there a reason that these restrictions are in place?